# How to clear textbox in setter if the value is wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, setter

I have textbox with the text property binded on field ItemCount. And I'm trying to clear it if i got wrong value. But texbox doesn't clear. Help me please. What is my mistake?

TextBox in xaml:

```
<TextBox Margin="5 15">
     <TextBox.Text>
          <Binding Path="ItemCount" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
          </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Binding implementing in viewmodel:

```
private int? _ItemCount;
        public int? ItemCount
        {
            get { return _ItemCount; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _ItemCount)
                {
                    if (value < 0)
                    {
                        _ItemCount = null;
                        throw new ApplicationException("Количество пластин не может быть отрицательным");

                    }
                    else if (value > ItemAmount)
                    {
                        _ItemCount = null;
                        throw new ApplicationException("Количество пластин не может превышать остаток");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _ItemCount = value;
                    }
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPD:**
I solved this problem by myself. I put my checks into try catch construction and made "_ItemCount = null" in catch in viewmodel implementation. So, it works now perfectly.

```
private int? _ItemCount;
    public int? ItemCount
    {
        get { return _ItemCount; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ItemCount)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (value < 0)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Количество пластин не может быть отрицательным");
                    }
                    else if (value > ItemAmount)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Количество пластин не может превышать остаток");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _ItemCount = value;
                    }
                }
                catch (ApplicationException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("kek");
                    _ItemCount = null;
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solve my problem. I put my cheks into try catch construction and made "_ItemCount = null" in catch.

Comment: In that case, you could write a self-answer. The future readers would profit from having an answer to your problem.

Comment: @Vlad I tried to do this, but i can't write answers now because of some restrictions of my account.